# img src attribute change using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the image based on the click. Like alternating clicks should have different image source. Something like a slideToggle. I saw that some people use toggleClass, but is there another way to achieve this?

My Code is as follows:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("img").click(function(){
            if ($("img").attr("src","down.png"))
            {
                $(this).attr("src","up.png");
            }

            else if ($("img").attr("src","up.png"))
            {
                $(this).attr("src","down.png");
            }
           })

    })
```

But unfortunately its not going into the else if loop.

Comment: Does your page only have one `img` element?

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` condition is wrong, you need a boolean expression:

```
if ($("img").attr("src") == "down.png") {
...
} else if ($("img").attr("src") == "up.png") {
..
}
```

Your original check of `$("img").attr("src","down.png")` is actually setting the image source to `down.png`, not checking for it.

Also, I believe you actually want this:

```
if ($(this).attr("src") == "down.png") {
...
} else if ($(this).attr("src") == "up.png") {
..
}
```

Your code will only evaluate the first image's source (of all the images on your page), this code checks the source of the clicked image.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the fixes that other answers have made, you also need to use `$(this)` throughout the function. `$("img").attr("src")` will get the `src` of the first image on the page, not the one that was clicked on.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").click(function(){

        if ($(this).attr("src") == "down.png") {
            $(this).attr("src","up.png");
        }

        else if ($(this).attr("src") == "up.png") {
            $(this).attr("src","down.png");
        }

    })
})
```

Comment: yes I have noted down your tips. :) Thanks! Also, is this the right way to go about such an effect of should I use something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").click(function(){
        var t = $(this);
        if (t.attr("src") == "down.png") {
            t.attr("src","up.png");
        }

        else if (t.attr("src") == "up.png") {
            t.attr("src","down.png");
        }

       });
});
```

I would probably simplify it to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("img").click(function(){
        var rc =  $(this).attr("src") == "down.png" ? 'up.png' : 'down.png';
         $(this).attr("src", rc);
     });
});
```

That line translates to something like this

```
var variable = (if statement true) ? (give value for true) : (give value for false)
```

The value is then directly saved in the `variable`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked :) is this approach to toggle the img src a good way to implement or is there a better way to go about it?

Comment: I just used one image each for that piece of code. Maybe that's why it worked. I made a note of using the "this" keyword too. :)

Comment: can anyone please explain what exactly this line of code does:var rc =  $(this).attr("src") == "down.png" ? 'up.png' : 'down.png';  I presume that it toggles between the 2 images but why down.png twice

Comment: @user2471553 look at my update, hope that explains it. it's basically like `if else` but the result is saved into a `variable`. The first `down.png` is tested with the `src` of the image. If they are equal, the variable will take the value of `up.png`, if they are not equal, the value will be `down.png`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't testing for the match in the if, also use `.prop()` not `.attr()` for the `src`.

Also you need to use `$(this)` inside the click handler, not `$('img')`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").click(function(){
        if ($(this).prop("src") == "down.png") {
            $(this).prop("src","up.png");
        } else if ($(this).prop("src") == "up.png") {
            $(this).prop("src","down.png");
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Can you explain why to use prop instead of attr?

Comment: Going through the attribute is not necessary, it requires slightly more work for the browser. `prop` directly accesses the DOM element object itself.

Comment: Yes, in the jquery api it mentions that the attr method is used. So, should we always use prop when dealing with such elements?